# LINQ Select last day when certain condition was met

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of objects like this

```
MyObject
  .StartDate
  .EndDate
  .Number
```

I need to know when was the last day the sum of numbers was above a certain number.
The number will only enter the sum for the day if it's between StartDate and EndDate.

```
var list = List<MyObject>();

from list
  where (list.Sum(x => x.Number) > 100)
  select lastdate
```

Is this possible with LINQ?

Comment: lastdate would be Max(EndDate/StartDate) wouldn't it?

Comment: lastdate should be the last day that the sum of numbers were above 100.
But the number will only enter the sum for the day if it's between StartDate and End date.

Answer (score 4):

assuming the list is in order:

```
var list = List<MyObject>();

var lastDate = list.First(item => list.Where(l => l.EndDate <= item.EndDate)
                                      .Sum(x => x.Number) > 100
                         )
                   .EndDate
```

if not just add an order:

```
var list = List<MyObject>();

var lastDate = list.OrderBy(item => item.EndDate)
                   .First(item => list.Where(l => l.EndDate <= item.EndDate)
                                      .Sum(x => x.Number) > 100
                         )
                   .EndDate
```

However you're re-scanning the loop for each item.  It will be more efficient with a simple loop:

```
DateTime endDate;
int total;
foreach(var item in list.OrderBy(item => item.EndDate))
{
   total += item.Number;
   if(total > 100)
   {
      endDate = item.EndDate;
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: The list is not ordered. The dates are completely random.
I need the last day the condition was met.

Comment: I like the simple loop version, it's far more clear what you are trying to do and as you said is even more efficient than trying to implement a one line solution.  Often times people get caught up in the notion that they **have** to use some technology or think that one line solutions are better just because there's less code to read.

Answer (score 1):

You may need an additional property to do this.  Not sure how to do it in a one line LINQ statement:

```
public class MyObjectWithSum
{
    public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
    public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
    public int Number {get;set;}
    public int SumAsOfEndDate {get;set;}
}

var list = new List<MyObjectWithSum>();

foreach(var item in list)
{
    item.SumAsOfEndDate = list.Sum(x => x.Number).Where(y => y.EndDate <= item.EndDate);
}

list.OrderBy(x => x.EndDate).First(x => x.SumAsOfEndDate > 100).EndDate;
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not add an additional property. I'm working from an object from the database.

Comment: @D Stanley's solution should work although I haven't tested it, but adding in the orderby to his solution is fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = items.Where(t => items.SkipWhile(tt => tt.EndDate != t.EndDate)
    .Sum(tt => tt.Number) > 100).First().EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var lastdate = list.OrderByDescending(l => l.EndDate)
         .First(l =>
             list.Where(s => s.StartDate <= l.EndDate && l.EndDate <= s.EndDate)
             .Sum(s => s.Number) > 100).EndDate;
```

We do not need to check any date, because the change to sum is dictated by changes to enddate.

So:

- Sort the list by descending enddate order, because we only need the last date.
- Search the first hit for which the sum of numbers is higher then 100:

  - Create a list of all the items which have been started before and ended or on after the enddate
  - Sum all the numbers

This way unnecesarry iterations are prevented and items which have ended later but also started later then the date you are checking, are ignored.